# Question about a metric space proving.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let us have an $(X,d)$ metric space. $U, V \subset X$ are disjoint, and $U\cup V = X$.

Let 
$$D(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}d(x,y)+1&\quad&\text{exactly one of $x$ and $y$ is in $U$}\\
d(x,y)&&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$
Prove that $D$ is a metric space in $X$.

I don't know how I should prove the $d(x,y)+1$ case.

$D(x,y) 
\geq 0$ works all the time, this is kind of obvious.
$D(x,y) = D(y,x)$ is same, but what to do with triangle inequality?

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that if $D(x,y)=0$, then $D$ cannot be equal to $d(x,y)+1\geq 1$, so $D(x,y)=d(x,y)=0$ and hence $x=y$.

For the triangle inequality fix $x,z\in X$. If $x,z\in U$ or $x,z\in V$, then $D(x,z)=d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)\leq D(x,y)+D(y,z)$. If exactly one of $x$ and $z$ belong to $U$ (say $x\in U,z\notin U$, the other case is similar) then $D(x,z)=d(x,z)+1\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)+1$. Now, each $y$ must belong to either $U$ or $V$. In the former case we have $D(x,y)=d(x,y)$ and $D(y,z)=d(y,z)+1$, and in the latter case we have $D(x,y)=d(x,y)+1$ and $D(y,z)=d(y,z)$. But in either case the triangle inequality is satisfied.

Comment: I was going to write basically this, I'm just really bad at typing in TeX.